# Using WPF Imaging classes - Getting image dimensions without reading the entire file

Tags: wpf, image, image-processing, file-io, metadata

Link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file) post I want to be able to read an image files height and width without reading in the whole file into memory.

In the post Frank Krueger mentions there is a way of doing this with some WPF Imaging classes. Any idea on how to do this??

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Winter.jpg"), BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
var width = bitmapFrame.PixelWidth;
var height = bitmapFrame.PixelHeight;
```

Comment: Note that this method will place a _lock_ on the image file. To avoid this, create a FileStream in a using block (with FileMode.Read, FileAccess.Read), and then create the BitmapFrame using the stream rather than the embedded URI. Kent himself uses this technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767250/using-bitmapframe-for-metadata-without-locking-the-file

Comment: @Charlie Why not put down the code as an alternative answer and earn some rep?

Answer (score 23):

Following Sir Juice's recommendation, here is some alternative code that avoids locking the image file:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    var width = bitmapFrame.PixelWidth;
    var height = bitmapFrame.PixelHeight;
}
```

Comment: I did a cursory check for memory allocation by wrapping this code with `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)`. I checked a 4k bitmap image (4096x2160, ~34MB on disk) and the amount of memory allocated was around 16kB.

Comment: Additionally, using [SysInternals ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) I observed only 4 `ReadFile` events at `(offset,length) = (0,16), (0,14), (14,4), (18,36)` for a grand total of 70 bytes read from the file. Fantastic!

Comment: @cod3monk3y referencing ProcMon

Comment: @Charlie : Is there any way to get image file size as well without loading the complete image in memory.